# How do you say 'How to turn 20 Euros into 120 Euros'?

Tags: translation

How do you say 'How to turn 20 Euros into 120 Euros'?

Comment: Was haben Deine eigenen Nachforschungen ergeben? Wieso waren deren Ergebnisse nicht befriedigend? Bitte immer erst selbst Wöterbücher etc. konsultieren und eigenes Bemühen dokumentieren, sonst wird hier schnell abgewertet und geschlossen.

Comment: This sentence specifically sounds very much like the subject of some spam email …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a question: Wie macht man aus 20 Euro 120 Euro?
As a statement: Wie man aus 20 Euro 120 Euro macht.